# NullPointerException thrown in onSaveInstanceState after exiting Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-lifecycle

I have an `Activity` called `HomeActivity`, which uses fragments `HomeFragment` and `OwnershipFragment`.

When I click a listview item in `HomeFragment`, a fragment transaction is carried out and `OwnershipFragment` is started.

In `OwnershipFragment` I have the following `onSaveInstanceState` method:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    for(int i = 0; i <mDirectors.size(); i++)
        mDirectors.get(i).updateFromForm();

    outState.putSerializable(DIRECTORS, mDirectors);
}
```

And in `onCreateView`...

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ownership, container, false);
    mFormContainer = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ownership_form_container);

    mManager = new SessionManager(getActivity());
    mDirectors = new ArrayList<Director>();

    if (savedInstanceState != null)
        mDirectors = (ArrayList<Director>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(DIRECTORS);
    else
        mDirectors = mManager.getDirectors();

    //Other stuff

    return rootView;

}
```

Basically, the app crashes after the following:

1. I click on the listview item that opens `OwnershipFragment`. (works fine)
2. I press the back button, which starts a transaction that goes back to `HomeFragment` and puts `OwnershipFragment` on the back stack. (works fine)
3. I turn my phone to change orientation to landscape mode. (works fine)
4. I turn it back to portrait and the app crashes and gives a `NullPointerException` at:

> for(int i = 0; i < mDirectors.size(); i++) //in the onSaveInstanceState method

I can't figure out why though because I can't find where `mDirectors` is assigned a `null` value. I'm not sure what other code to provide, so just let me know and i'll put it in.

**Why is `onSaveInstanceState` of `OwnershipFragment` called in the first place if the current fragment displayed is `HomeFragment`?**

Here's my Logcat:

```
07-15 11:28:24.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12150): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-15 11:28:24.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12150): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-15 11:28:24.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at com.opendoors.core.OwnershipFragment.onSaveInstanceState(OwnershipFragment.java:204)
07-15 11:28:24.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at android.app.Fragment.performSaveInstanceState(Fragment.java:1840)
07-15 11:28:24.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState(FragmentManager.java:1598)
07-15 11:28:24.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveAllState(FragmentManager.java:1655)
07-15 11:28:24.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at android.app.Activity.onSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1233)
07-15 11:28:24.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(FragmentActivity.java:546)
07-15 11:28:24.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at com.opendoors.core.HomeActivity.onSaveInstanceState(HomeActivity.java:220)
07-15 11:28:24.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1181)
07-15 11:28:24.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1233)
07-15 11:28:24.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3778)
07-15 11:28:24.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:152)
07-15 11:28:24.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1288)
07-15 11:28:24.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-15 11:28:24.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-15 11:28:24.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
07-15 11:28:24.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 11:28:24.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-15 11:28:24.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
07-15 11:28:24.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
07-15 11:28:24.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: one of these methods returns null `if (savedInstanceState != null)
        mDirectors = (ArrayList<Director>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(DIRECTORS);
    else
        mDirectors = mManager.getDirectors();`

Comment: I put a breakpoint in right before those statements, and at the time of the error they're not called. I don't think `onCreateView` for `OwnershipFragment` is even called at all when I change the orientation of `HomeFragment`

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment, change you definition of `mDirectors` to

`ArrayList<Director> mDirectors = new ArrayList<Director>();`

or check for null in your for as

```
for(int i = 0; mDirectors != null && i < mDirectors.size(); i++)
```

Comment: Why is `onSaveInstanceState` of `OwnershipFragment` called in the first place if the current fragment is `HomeFragment`?

Comment: Would it help to post the `HomeFragment` code and/or the `HomeActivity` code?